# how to disable validation rule of yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I created registration form with using gii code generator in yii framework. Gii code generator created all validation rules in fields like fname,lname,email,etc.
         Now I am trying to put my custom validation rule in all fields. so i need to disable other validation rule in that field which is en-billet by yii framework.

how am I suppose to do that.

Comment: post your rules method in model, and tell us what field is the one that you want to disable validating

Comment: array('firstName', 'length', 'max'=>20),
array('lastName', 'length', 'max'=>40), I want to disable firstName and lasrName's validation

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have this in your model :

```
public function rules(){
return array(
  array('firstName', 'length', 'max'=>20),
  array('lastName', 'length', 'max'=>40),
);
}
```

this means the validation method checks the length of `firstName` and `lastName`, and checks that their length should not be greater than 20 and 40.

If you want to remove this rule from validating, you can simply remove the line, and put your custom validation rules in it.

- [***List of validation rules in Yii framework***](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/)
- [***Create your own validation rule***](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also extend class **CActiveRecord** and overwrite the `save()` method which accepts to properties and set the `$runValidation` to **false**.

this is the function in CActiveRecord that needs to be overwrited:

```
public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null)
{
    if(!$runValidation || $this->validate($attributes))
        return $this->getIsNewRecord() ? $this->insert($attributes) : $this->update($attributes);
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can uncomment/remove the default rules and replace it with your custom rules.